# Gradle test log4j.xml

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2

Sorry, if this isn't enough information, new to gradle, let me know if more is needed.
I have a log4j2.xml in a config folder that I define in a gradle.properties file.

```
project.ext.logConfigFile="./config/log4j2.xml"
```

The structure of my project

project
    src
    test
    lib
    config
        log4j2.xml

Now when I run gradle test, it says that it can't find the log4j2 configuration.

This is what my build.gradle file looks like..

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["test"]
        }
    }
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }
    }
}


test {
    testLogging {
        outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
        showStandardStreams = true
        events "PASSED", "STARTED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
        afterSuite { desc, result ->
            if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                println "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Been dinking around with things I found on the internet, that's why all those statements in the "testLogging" part. But basically, I have LOGGER.info() statements that aren't coming up because it defaults to errors only.

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Can I tell gradle test exactly where to go for my log4j2.xml? Something like this? Though I don't think this works....

```
tasks.withType(Test) { 
     systemProperty 'log4j.configuration', logConfigFile
}
```

A little stuck right now. Thanks!

Comment: What is this doing `tasks.withType(Test) `?

Comment: So...I think this makes all of the Tests take this system property? meaning all test will take that log42.xml file. Really not positive of this, I grabbed it from somewhere in the internet. Happy to get rid of it if it's not the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in `src/test/resources`. That comes first on the classpath during testing. Then configure log4j to load from classpath, not a file path; I think that’s the default behavior anyway

Comment: This works too, but involves me changing the directory structure, I found a different solution which I could've got if I just RTFM. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Believe I solved the problem, you just define where the resources are in the sourceSets also. It will look there for the log4j2.xml.

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["test"]
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["config"]
        }
    }
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So inventing your own project structure rather than following the [convention](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) that I’d suggested is preferable? Don’t know about you, but this would be fine if I were paid by the hour

Comment: Agree not preferable but was working with an existing code base that i didnt want to change too much. Agree should eventually move to convention.